# Nlog Not Creating log file after changing Path of log file dynamically from code

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

this code is not work properly. I am trying create logfile on runtime but when i change logpath, need to restart the application to create logpath. it create logfile after restart the application.

i want to create logfile on Runtime. 
Please Help Me...

```
 private static void ChangeLogPath(string path)
 {
  try
    {
     var Formatpath = path.Replace(@"\", "/");
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     Logger.Info("FilePath config File " + 
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile.ToString()); 
     xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
     XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("configuration");
     foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
     {
      var Childnods = node.LastChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.Attributes;
                for (int i = 0; i < Childnods.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Childnods[i].Name == "fileName")
                    {
                        Childnods[i].Value = Formatpath + "/Loge.txt";
                    }
                    if (Childnods[i].Name == "archiveFileName")
                    {
                        Childnods[i].Value = Formatpath + "/Archives/{#}_Log.txt";
                    }
                }
            }  
     xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
           ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("nlog");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: is this .net core? how are you setting `path`?

Comment: its not .Net Core , its Windows form application

Comment: this code change the path for logfile but not create at a time.

Comment: so how are you changing it?

Comment: I have Edit the story could be more understand able.

Comment: is this possible to create log file by click on save Button ?? @viveknuna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative use a NLog Config Variable for the LogDirectory, and then just change that variable. Ex:

```
<nlog>
   <variable name="LogDirectory" value="C:/Users/DefaultUser/" />

   <targets>
       <target type="file" name="logfile" fileName="${var:LogDirectory}/Log.txt" fileName="${var:LogDirectory}/Archives/{#}_Log.txt" />
   </targets>

   <rules>
       <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then maybe something like this:

```
 private static void ChangeLogPath(string path)
 {
    try
    {
     var Formatpath = path.Replace(@"\", "/");
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     Logger.Info("FilePath config File " + 
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile.ToString()); 
     xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
     var variableList = root.SelectNodes("/configuration/nlog/variable");
     foreach (XmlNode variable in variableList)
     {
         var name = node.SelectSingleNode("@name").InnerText;
         if (name == "LogDirectory")
         {
             var value = node.SelectSingleNode("@value");
             value.InnerText = Formatpath;
         }
     }
     xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
     ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("nlog");
     LogManager.Configuration.Variables["LogDirectory"] = Formatpath;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     Logger.Error(e.ToString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: this code is also create directory and log file, but not create at run time it creates log after restarting the application.

Answer (score 0):

NLog currently fails to detect file-changes to the app.config.

You can try and force an explicit unload and load of NLog Configuration like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("nlog");
LogManager.Configuration = null;
var newLoadedConfig = LogManager.Configuration;
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2482

Comment: not working with this code too, any other possible solution for it?